# On Monterey Finder - Is the Path Bar selection of a parent folder single-click or double-click?

Tags: finder, mouse, path, click

[image]
This is a Path Bar at the bottom of a Finder Window in MacOS Monterey.

From what I *remember* to go to a parent folder you would *double-click* the folder in the Path Bar. This is consistent with how you open other folders in MacOS.

Now to navigate in my Path Bar - I have to single click the folder in the Path bar - if I double-click - it acts twice and takes me up two levels.

I feel like I'm going nuts, I can't find a preference setting, and my mouse doesn't double-click for anything else.

My question is: ***On Monterey Finder - Is the Path Bar selection of a parent folder single-click or double-click?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have changed to a single click in Monterey:

> You can also do any of the following:
>  Show a folder’s subfolders in
> the Finder window: Click the folder in the path bar.

[support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1774/mac)

Comment: What?!?!?! (Well done)